# Get base64 from sound url in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a example sound url here: `http://awexsoft.rf.gd/testing/test.mp3` and i want to make a base64 from this url. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You can read it into a binary array `.then` convert the result to base64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const res = await fetch('http://awexsoft.rf.gd/testing/test.mp3');
const data = await res.arrayBuffer();

const b64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(data)));

console.log(b64);
```

Comment: I'm mildly annoyed at your use of `await` :)